# my bundle.js doesn't seem to be created

Tags: javascript, webpack, path

I am building a simple app with the use of webpack to combine all my modules. My webpack seem to be running (although, I have battled its not-working).
Now it looks like a bundle.js necessary to see my app cannot be found. I get this error:

[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYmS2.png)

So here are my files that might cause the issue

[the config.webpack.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEYOR.png)

my packageJSON

```
{
 "name": "quiz",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "",
 "main": "app.js",
 "scripts": {
   "test": "mocha specs"
 },
 "author": "",
 "license": "ISC",
 "devDependencies": {
   "mocha": "^3.4.2",
   "webpack": "1.12.15"
 }
}
```

and the html file that looks for the bundle.js file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Quiz game</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src = "build.js "></script>
    <div>
    Quiz game
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas on what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

First,

Probably, you can change your project structure a little as webpack cli will find the webpack.config.js file under root folder by default.

```
  webpack-demo
  |- package.json
+ |- webpack.config.js
  |- /dist
    |- index.html
  |- /src
    |- index.js
```

Second, 
you may change your webpack.config.js a little bit by require path to point out the output path clearly:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  }
};
```

Third,

If your index.html is under the same folder as bundle.js in dist folder,

```
 <script src="bundle.js"></script>
```

is correct. But put it at the bottom the body, so that it won't block rendering and can manipulate DOM when page load.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Quiz game</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    Quiz game
    </div>
    <script src="build.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, Ben! Everything's worked :) I need to bear in mind that the structure in webpack is the key!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the build.js file cannot be found because the path to the file in the index.html is wrong, it should be should be `<script src = "/build.js "></script>` in your index.html not `<script src = "build.js "></script>`

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't work and I have tried that before... :/

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the build.js path to the file.

You're missing just a small part.

Try this:
Place a / in your src right before your "build.js"